# Keras multi gpu memory usage is different

Tags: keras, gpu, equals

I try to use 4 gpus in my labtop. so i use the command

> new_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)

It works very well, but there are one problem.
only the first gpu has more gpu memory.
below is my code and the state of my gpus memory checked by `watch nvidia-smi`
[image]

[image]

The first gpu0 has increase only when make up the model before command `new_model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus=4)`

in that time, 4000MiB memory occurs in the first gpu0.

Why this unfaired gpu usage occurs?
and how can i use the 4 gpus equally?
please give me the hint.

thanks a lot.